# Issue with spaces in package name when Siebel Webservice integrated with Java application

Tags: java, webservice-client, wsdl2java

I am trying to invoke a webservice developed in Siebel from a Java application. Using the WSDL i was provided, i generated the stubs/skeleton using Apache Axis.

Strangely in Seibel, there are objects under package names having spaces. This is represented as %20 in the WSDL. http://www.siebel.com/xml/Test%20RR%20Spec%20Service%20IO which ideally represents Test RR Spec Service IO.

Using the wsdl2java emitter class, when i use this WSDL, i do get the classes but obviuosly did not compile. So i tried to replace %20 with "_" underscore. When i invoke the webservice, this package does not recognized by the Seibel webservice and the client receives exception stating invalid element.

Any suggestions of how to create the Java client for Seibel webservice application which has spaces in it (represented as %20)?

Thanks,
Gokul

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it: a package name with spaces doesn't sound legal.  I doubt that Seible wrote a Java class in an illegal package.  Something else is wrong.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: Refer: http://siebel.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/siebel-dev-l/20-in-wsdl-file-2752154. It is not a problem either with Apache Axis or with seibel. Both of them are doing their work perfectly. The problem i am facing is to somehow make sure my RAW xml is having the correct package name.